# How can you keep resource files (localization) in subfolders?

Tags: c#, localization, internationalization, embedded-resource, globalization

I'd like to categories my resource files by folder, so I can provide a structure that's easier to manage as it grows.

Something like:

```
/Resources/errors/Errors.resx
/Resources/exceptions/Exceptions.resx
/Resources/responseMessages/ResponseMessages.resx
```

That way as I add translations for each it's easier to manage. I'm surprised you can't do this off the bat, because having 50 files in a single folder is annoying to manage.

EDIT: Answering my own question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a way to do it manually. It messed me up when I didn't originally add the resources to /Resources (I had a different root folder), so I recreated the resource files in the .Net Resources folder and then modified the designer files:

changed:

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Resources.Errors {
```

to:

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Resources {
```

and changed:

```
new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyProject.Web.Resources.Errors", typeof(Exceptions).Assembly);
```

to:

```
new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("MyProject.Web.Resources.Errors.Errors", typeof(Exceptions).Assembly);
```

I can now access my resources as intended:

```
Console.WriteLine(Resources.Errors.FileNotFound);
```